# Adjust Selected ListViewItem TextBlock Style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am having a strange issue. I am not sure if this is a bug, or if I am simply misunderstanding something as I am fairly new to WPF (Probably the latter).

In my project, I have a `ListView` that displays items in a similar fashion to that seen of Windows Explorer using Icon view. I have outlined a control template that consists of a an `Image` element, and a `TextBlock` element below it. My goal is to adjust the maximum height of the `TextBlock` when the `ListViewItem` is selected. This is so the name of the Items will adjust from being trimmed with an ellipsis to showing the full name of the item.

When the item is selected however, instead of adjusting the maximum height of ***only*** the selected item's `TextBlock`, it adjusts all `TextBlock`s for each item whether it is actively selected or not.

I have researched for an answer, but have not found anything similar to this particular issue. This link is a similar concept, but without my problem.

[WPF - ListView Item on Selected change Font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917704/wpf-listview-item-on-selected-change-font-size)

Some of my other methods have consisted of one `ControlTemplate` with triggers for the style changes, or `ItemContainerStyle` instead of explicitly a `ControlTemplate`, which all seemed to give the same undesired result.

How can I achieve this functionality? Is it possible with `ControlTemplate`?

Here is some of my XAML code:

**ListView**

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemViewer">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Margin="10"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemNormal}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelected}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

**ControlTemplates**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemNormal" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Border x:Name="ItemBoxBorder" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="90"
              Margin="5"
              MaxWidth="90"
              Width="90"
              x:Name="ItemBox">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Source="{StaticResource NewImage}"
                       Width="64" Height="64"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemDescription"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           MaxWidth="90"
                           MaxHeight="30"
                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </Grid.ToolTip>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="ItemBoxBorder"  Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightMouseHoverColorBrush}"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemSelected" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Border x:Name="ItemBoxBorder" Background="{StaticResource SelectedItemBrush}"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource HighlightBorderColorBrush}"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="90"
              Margin="5"
              MaxWidth="90"
              Width="90"
              x:Name="ItemBox">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Source="{StaticResource NewImage}"
                       Width="64" Height="64"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemDescription"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           MaxWidth="90"
                           MaxHeight="125"
                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </Grid.ToolTip>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the issue with ms_dos's implementation.

[This image shows I have the item with a short description selected. This is the height all items should remain if they are not selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNdmJ.png)

[In this image, you'll see the item with the long description is selected. However, both items extend their height, but only the selected one should grow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me8Cs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two separate control templates for this. Just take the `ItemContainerStyle` property of the `ListView` and use a control template like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemViewer">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Margin="10" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Border x:Name="ItemBoxBorder"
                                    Background="Green"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                      MinHeight="90"
                                      Margin="5"
                                      MaxWidth="90"
                                      Width="90"
                                      x:Name="ItemBox">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                               Width="64"
                                               Height="64" />
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="ItemDescription"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                   Text="{Binding}"
                                                   MaxWidth="90"
                                                   MaxHeight="125"
                                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <Grid.ToolTip>
                                        <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                    </Grid.ToolTip>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                         Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="ItemBoxBorder"
                                            Property="Background"
                                            Value="Red" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="ItemDescription"
                                            Property="TextElement.FontSize"
                                            Value="20" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="ItemBoxBorder"
                                            Property="Height"
                                            Value="135" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                         Value="false">
                                    <Setter TargetName="ItemBoxBorder"
                                            Property="Height"
                                            Value="90" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Take a look at the `ControlTemplate.Triggers` section. Basically you use the `Trigger` property to control which property the trigger should handle... in our case the `IsSelected` from the ListView. And with the `Setter` you define the property and the value for the changes of the `ListViewItem` control. The `TargetName` of the `Setter` refers to the `x:Name` of the control which you define in the `ControlTemplate` section.

I hope this example helps you with your problem!

Greets
ms_dos

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, this doesn't quite resolve my problem. Please take a look at my edit with the attached photos. With this code, all the items still grow with the selected, although only the selected item should have it's height increased.

Comment: Ok, now I see where you want to go! In that case just add another `Trigger`for `IsSelected` with value `false`. Also you have to adress the height property of the border control `ItemBoxBorder`. To keep the items lined up on the top I added a `VerticalAlignment="Top"` to the border control. I updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Ahh! Ugh, I never would have thought of that!...Actually, upon testing it seems it is not even necessary to set a condition for `IsSelected` as `false`. As long as I set the `ItemBoxBorder` with `VerticalAlignment="Top"` it behaves exactly like I wanted. Thanks again! :)